# How to fit layout xml which is getting from server in Android

Tags: android, xml

Hello I am curious for this topic. Here I am getting xml layout from a web service and now when this xml contains the `button` then app should show `button` and if xml contain `button` and `textview` then app should show `button` and `textview`.

Do I here have to parse the `xml` then create the views dynamically ? but this approach will make things more hard because a lot of properties any view have and searching methods and  setting correct position in view container looks like is not simple.

If anyone have experience with this kind of system then please hint how you guys did this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I here have to parse the xml then create the views dynamically ?

Yes.

> but this approach will make things more hard because a lot of properties any view have and searching methods and setting correct position in view container looks like is not simple.

Correct. You may wish to revisit your plan ("I am getting xml layout from a web service") and try to come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks again Mark :) +1 But Is it possible to set that xml in setcontentview direct ?

Comment: @Williams: "But Is it possible to set that xml in setcontentview direct ?" -- no. Android cannot inflate an XML file. It can only inflate XML resources, and yours is not an XML resource.

Comment: Yes I agree but If I go for this approach then it won't be easy and time taking process. Can you please hint if you have better solution for this ?

Comment: @Williams: Limit your options to only a handful of pre-defined layouts, where the server provides light customization instructions for those layouts. Or, see if somebody else has written a library that basically performs inflation of layout XML files instead of layout resources. I am not aware of such a library, and maintaining such a library would be a serious pain.

Comment: Correct I am also thinking to do same. It would be impossible to cover all properties of all views. thanks so much again :)